# ¿Como cerrar Navegador desde C# despues de finalizar el código?

Tags: c#

actualmente quiero cerrar el navegador despues de ejecutar una rutina diaria, llevo días intentandolo, incluso con selenium pero por cuestiones de versiones entre selenium y los navegadores no me permite usarlo, por lo tanto ya no uso selenium

Estuve trabajando en este código pero al final no me cierra el navegador, se queda abierto, espero puedan ayudarme, saludos!

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] uri = new string [5] { "http://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.linkedin.com", "http://www.stackoverflow.com", "http://www.microsoft.com" };
        int urlCurrentIndex = 4;
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Daily Routine\n");
        while (urlCurrentIndex < 5)
        {
            foreach (string i in uri){
                var exe = new ProcessStartInfo("explorer.exe");
                exe.Arguments = i;
                Process.Start(exe);
                var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

                if (process != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Routine in progress...");
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    process.Close();
                    urlCurrentIndex++;
                    
                    if (urlCurrentIndex <= 4)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Routine has been completed.");
                        process.Kill();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Routine failed.");
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Te muestra algún error?

Comment: No veo que estés usando selenium.

Comment: Le muestra el mensaje de : Console.WriteLine("Daily Routine has been completed.");  ?????

Comment: hace falta el navegador completo? tal vez un [webclient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0) sea suficiente

Comment: Y si mejor haces una llamada http usando HttpClient desde c#, asi obtendras una respuesta y no necesitas abrir ningun navegador.

Comment: Solo no cerraba el navegador cuando terminara de recorrer el arreglo, pero ya logré solucionarlo con otro método adicional, gracias chicos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre solucionar el problema, sé que no es la mejor opción pero funciona, se los comparto, se que a alguien le puede servir

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    { "http://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.linkedin.com", "http://www.stackoverflow.com", "http://www.microsoft.com" };

        int urlCurrentIndex = 4;
        Console.WriteLine("Daily Routine is running...");
        Console.WriteLine("Please, don't close Terminal\n");
        while (urlCurrentIndex < 5)
        {
            foreach (string i in uri)
            {
                var exe = new ProcessStartInfo("explorer.exe");
                exe.Arguments = i;
                Process.Start(exe);
                var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

                if (process != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Routine in progress...");
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    process.Close();
                    urlCurrentIndex++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Routine failed.");
                }
            }
```

Se agrega esta sección de código para cerrar los procesos de los navegadores elegidos

```
            Thread.Sleep(30000);
            Process[] AllProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (var process in AllProcesses)
            {
                if (process.MainWindowTitle != "")
                {
                    string s = process.ProcessName.ToLower();
                    if (s == "iexplore" || s == "iexplorer" || s == "chrome" || s == "firefox" || s == "msedge")
                        process.Kill();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Routine has been finished successfully!");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
    }
```